# main method assistance required

Tags: java

I have written the following code, I have managed to test the Get statements, but how do I test the void statements in the code below as you can see I have used flygplan2.andraHojd to change the int, but how do I show the result of that change and can I show it in the skrivaUTinfo class)

please see code below

```
//Klass
public class FlygPlan {
    int hojd;
    int flygriktning;
    int hastighet;
    String modellbeteckning;
    //Konstruktor
    public FlygPlan(int hojd, int flygriktning, int hastighet, String modellbeteckning) {
        this.hojd = hojd;
        this.flygriktning = flygriktning;
        this.hastighet = hastighet;
        this.modellbeteckning = modellbeteckning;


    }
    //Main-metoden
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlygPlan flygplan1 = new FlygPlan (1000, 1, 60 , "Hejsan");
        FlygPlan flygplan2 = new FlygPlan (10, 4, 70, "Sohail");
        flygplan1.skrivaUt();


        flygplan2.andraHojd(60,70);



    }

    public void andraHojd(int hojd, int nyHojd)
    {
        hojd = nyHojd;
    }
    public static int visaHojd(int hojd)
    {
        return hojd;
    }
    public void andraRiktning(int flygriktning, int nyFlygriktning)
    {
        flygriktning = nyFlygriktning;
    }
    public static int visaRiktning(int flygriktning)
    {
        return flygriktning;
    }
    public void andraHastighet(int hastighet, int nyHastighet)
    {
        hastighet = nyHastighet;
    }
    public static int visaHastighet(int hastighet)
    {
        return hastighet;
    }
    public void andraModellBeteckning(int modellbeteckning, int nyModellbeteckning)
    {
        modellbeteckning = nyModellbeteckning;
    }
    public static String visaModellBeteckning(String modellbeteckning)
    {
        return modellbeteckning;

    }

    public void skrivaUt()
    {
    System.out.println(" flygets modellbeteckning är " +modellbeteckning);
    System.out.println(" flygets flygriktning är " +flygriktning);
    System.out.println(" flygets hastighet är " +hastighet);
    System.out.println(" flyget flyger på  höjd(m) " +hojd);



    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I see wrong with this code initially.

Why have you made your getters `static`?  This means that they're not associated with any particular object instance, and so would not in fact be able to work.

However, you don't notice this because you *pass a value* into your "getter", which the method *returns straight back out*.  Is this intended (presumably not, because the method does nothing)?  Getters typically take no arguments, and return an instance field, e.g.:

```
public int visaHojd()
{
    return hojd;
}
```

In a similar sense, you're passing two arguments into your setter, which is also unusual - especially as once again your method does nothing (it sets *a local variable* and then exits, making no "externally visible" changes).  The first `hojd` argument that you pass in *shadows* the `hojd` field and hides it, so the field never gets updated.  You could write the setter simply as:

```
public void andraHojd(int nyHojd)
{
    hojd = nyHojd;
}
```

---

To answer your actual question about testing, you need to think about what the methods are actually declared to do.  What is the declared effect of a setter, in the context of the class?  For this simple class, it means that the next call to the getter will return that value.  So you can't test that method in isolation; you need to invoke the methods together to test that they fulfil this requirement.

Something like this perhaps:

```
public void testSetter() {
    int testValue = 42; // arbitrary
    FlygPlan testObj = new FlygPlan();

    // do the test
    testObj.andraHojd(testValue);
    int result = testObj.visaHojd();

    // assert correctness, i.e. that the same value was returned from the
    // getter as was passed to the setter (would usually use something like
    // JUnit here)
    assert testValue == result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void` means method returns nothing.

One way to test is put a `System.out.println()` and check whether it is invoked or not.
And you can print the value using getter after setter is invoked.

I do see some issues in your code:

A. `static` getter methods to return instance members;

B. getter usually doesn't take any parameters.
I don't think so you want to do that.

```
public static int visaHastighet(int hastighet)
{
    return hastighet;
}
```

It should be like:

```
public int visaHastighet()
{
    return hastighet;
}
```

C. Your setter is not rightly placed as it only modifies local variable.

```
public void andraHojd(int hojd, int nyHojd)
{
    hojd = nyHojd;
}
```

It should be like:

```
public void andraHojd(int hojd)
{
    hojd = nyHojd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void andraHojd(int hojd, int nyHojd)
{
    hojd = nyHojd;
}
```

This setter method, and those like it, are probably not what you intend.  You are passing in an integer variable as a parameter `(hojd)` and setting it's value based on another method parameter `(nyHojd)`.  When the method exists, this state change will be lost.  I think what you want is:

```
public void andraHojd(int hojd)
{
    this.hojd = hojd;
}
```

As far as your question:

> how do I test the void statements in the code below as you can see I
>   have used flygplan2.andraHojd to change the int, but how do I show the
>   result of that change and can I show it in the skrivaUTinfo class)

You can write a `toString()` method on the class to print out it's member fields and simply call that on an instance of `FlygPlan`

@Override
public String toString() { 
    return "hojd = " + this.hojd" + " flygriktning = " this.flygriktning;
}